# How to define Netlify function endpoint as POST?

Tags: javascript, serverless, netlify

I am new to serverless and am trying to get my head around it. So I've created a function on netlify using `GET` and it works fine.

Then I wanted a `POST` endpoint so I followed the same format and created a similar function. But then I sent a `POST` request to this new function. On checking the console.log on the server I realise that it's being read as a request with a `GET` method (httpMethod:'GET'). And then I realised that I have not defined the endpoint method which I would have done on a normal server.

But I have no idea how to do that.

Question

**Is there a different way to do a GET function and POST function on netlify or serverless?**

If the answer is Yes, then please guide me on this.

If the answer is No, and the functions are written in the same way, then can someone advise me why my `POST` request is being read as `GET` by netlify?

Here's the code from the function on codesandbox .. https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-function-2xebuf?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the answer to this so that it serves as a reminder to me and if it helps someone in the future who has a similar issues

Thanks to @alessiopremoli for sharing that one **can't explicitly define to what verb the function handler should respond to** .. that answered my first question : **Is there a different way to do a GET function and POST function on netlify or serverless?**

The second issue that I faced was that **my POST request was being read by netlify as GET**.. I realised what the issue was.. there's a setting for redirect rules in the netlify.toml file that simplifies the URL to the api.. so you can type "site.com/api/functionName.js" instead of "site.com/.netlify/functions/functionName.js"

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/blog/:splat"
```

and I was using this for my api routes as

```
[[redirects]]
from="/api/*"
to="/.netlify/functions/:splat"
```

to simplify the access to my api route.. but I didn't realise that that by default the status code for this redirect is 301 which changes the method to `GET` and this was also changing the method of my request. So for those who face this issue, I hope this helps.

**If it's a POST request and you are using a redirect option then ensure that you add the status of 200 or just call the function using the default path that you've set eg "site.com/.netlify/functions/functionName.js"**

So changing the redirect rule to the one as below fixed the issue for me

```
[[redirects]]
from="/api/*"
to="/.netlify/functions/:splat"
status=200
```

Here's the link to the netlify support team that helped resolve this issue that explains it better (https://answers.netlify.com/t/does-using-the-redirects-route-to-a-function-call-change-the-method-of-the-request-from-post-to-get/55760/5)

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, you can't explicitly define to what verb the function handler should respond to, I usually set a check on the event verb:

```js
if (event.httpMethod !== 'POST') {
    return {
        statusCode: 501,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Not Implemented" }),
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alessiopremoli for the update. So a POST request would be read as a POST request by any function on netlify.. right? It should depend on the request being sent to the API handler.. but I am 100% sure I am sending a POST request as it's from postman and the API handler is displaying the event property `httpMethod` as`GET`.. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: @AlimBolar, yes, if you call it as POST the handler should get an `httpMethod` as POST. if you can share your code in your question I can investigate further (both the handler and the caller)

Comment: thanks.. here's the link to the codesandbox.io.. https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-function-2xebuf?file=/src/index.js  ... let me know if you could access it.. and try to send some JSON data to it by postman

Comment: @AlimBolar your code looks good but I think that you better put your index.js inside a `functions` folder and rename it properly (`createRating.js`) so netlify can understad that's a function to be served under the `.netlify/functions` endpoint.

Comment: That's actually exactly how i have it in netlify.. as .netlify/functions/createRating.js .. but when i send a post request to this function with some JSON content the body is empty and the httpMethod is `GET`...:-(..

Comment: figured out the issue and have posted it in the answer.. I was using redirects in the netlify.toml file which was converting my POST request to GET..

Comment: it seems I was not 100% right about the redirects part.. I had to define the status code and the redirect worked as expected.. https://answers.netlify.com/t/does-using-the-redirects-route-to-a-function-call-change-the-method-of-the-request-from-post-to-get/55760/5